# Fallout Shelter Game Save lost

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have the Lenovo Yoga Tab 2 and it has it quirks. Every now and then I will come across the problem of opening an app, and on my tab I figured out if I delete the app and re-download it, it will work again. it's happened on my snapchat, clash of clans, facebook. The list goes on and I've done it for all and never lost data (most of it was stored on the cloud anyways).

But, it happened to Fallout Shelter and when I redownloaded it, I was back at the tutorial and had nothing. I spent money on this game and now I have no motive to play it.. Are there any solutions?

Comment: Sorry if the save is gone then its just all gone :/

Comment: There's no option to restore purchases/data in the settings? (I've had similar problems with apps, so I've started to check for things like that when I download them.)

Comment: I'll have to check again, but I've gone all the way through the options I thought.

Comment: @AshleyNunn No, all purchased content is tied to each save as well for these games.

Comment: you might try contacting Bethesda support and see if they can help you out because they should have the real money receipts on their side. But the progress in your vault is local only so it's probably gone. :(

Comment: Not that it helps your current situation but there is an app on the app store that backs up saves for this game.

Comment: @kenjara I am on an Android device. When you say app store do you mean Google Play?

Comment: @NealC On the play store search for fallout shelter backup.

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, if you re-installed the game, the save folder will be deleted. So there's no chance of your progress being restored.

If you didn't reinstall the game, you can go to the save files in Android and restore them.

*I moved my game from one Android device to another and didn't lose any progress by backing the save file*